# TabLayout change selected TabSize

Tags: android

```
TextView title = (TextView)(((LinearLayout ((LinearLayout) mTabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(tabPosition)).getChildAt(1));title.setTextSize(...);
```

I got the tabs `Textview` in `Tablayout` by this method,but this method is strange，if i `setTextSize(10)`,it works,tab has small textsize,but when i `setTextSize` above 10,it always use default textsize whatever tab is selected or not.i think it only has two default textsize,anyone met this question,how can i set other textsize for it?

Comment: Maybe you can try with custom TextView layout

Comment: thanks ,i use tab.setCustomView(),but setupwithViewPager not works,  use tablayout.setOnTabSelectedListener() and ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener() replace.

Comment: I think you can share your code so i can help with see what the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void tabLayoutInit() {
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = mTabLayout.newTab();
        View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tablayout_customview, null);
        tab.setCustomView(view);
        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout_customView_tv);
        text.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tab_resource)[i]);
        if (i==0) {
            text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_f));
            text.setTextSize(DensityUtils.px2sp(MainActivity.this,50));
            mTabLayout.addTab(tab);
            continue;
        }
        text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.fireBar));
        text.setTextSize(DensityUtils.px2sp(MainActivity.this,40));
        mTabLayout.addTab(tab);
    }
    final TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener listener =
            new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabLayout);
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(listener);
    mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) tab.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.tabLayout_customView_tv);
            textView.setTextSize(DensityUtils.px2sp(MainActivity.this,50));
            textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_f));
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) tab.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.tabLayout_customView_tv);
            textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.fireBar));
            textView.setTextSize(DensityUtils.px2sp(MainActivity.this,40));
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: this is my solution,tabLayout.setupwithViewpager not works,so i use Listener replace.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one.. You can set each tabs text size and other properties.. You can take a look here for more info [Custom tablayout](https://programmingcode4life.blogspot.my/2016/07/custom-tablayout-android.html)

```
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabs.getChildAt(0);
        int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
        for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
            ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(j);
            int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++) {
                View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
                // Get TextView Element
                if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                  // change font
                  ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(tf);
                  // change color
                  ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                  // change size
                  ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTextSize(18);
                  // change padding
                  tabViewChild.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                  //..... etc...
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: i apply these code in my project,but it has same problem,setTextSize() only provide two TextSize type...